# How to make hovering a button changes background of a different element

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

[Website in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB5sx.jpg)

What I want to happen is that when someone hovers one of the 3 buttons "Signature Events" "Weddings" "Le Coq d'Or" the background and content of the div above it change. The div above it is static, it's not a slider. Just a styled HTML block.

I've just started getting into JS within the last week or so, and this seems like it could be done with JS switch, but I'm not sure. I don't even know what to search to get info on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a data attribute with the target class and a little bit jQuery Code.

```js
$('button').hover(
  function() {
    $('header').addClass($(this).attr("data-class")).text($(this).attr("data-title"));
  }, function() {
    $('header').removeClass($(this).attr("data-class")).text($('header').attr("data-title"));
  }
);
```

```css
header{
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/600/');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 180px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header.backgroundOne{
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/600/');
}
header.backgroundTwo{
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/600/');
}
header.backgroundThree{
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/600/');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header data-title="Header Image">
  Header Image
</header>
<button data-class="backgroundOne" data-title="Title One">
  Change Header 1
</button>
<button data-class="backgroundTwo" data-title="Title Two">
  Change Header 2
</button>
<button data-class="backgroundThree" data-title="Title Three">
  Change Header 3
</button>
```

So if you hover a button, the data-class attribute value from this button is added as a class to your header element. If you stop hovering, the class is removed again so that the default image is shown.

Comment: Perfect, I knew it was something simple. I have content within the header that would change as well. For example, when hovering over the "Weddings" button, the text on the header would change to weddings and have a line of copy below. How would I make the content be switched aswell?

Comment: I updated the snippet. If it is okay, please accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For such questions, I always feel the need to provide a css-only answer since I think nowadays far too much JavaScript (especially JQuery) is used to perform tasks which can be done with pure CSS. Mostly but not always CSS is more performant because it must not be executed and gets cached.

Please see the snippet below. It uses flexbox and the [order css rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp), which both have a fairly good browser support (unless you must support cripple browsers like older internet explorer versions).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

button {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 18px;
}

.wrapper > div {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 36px 0 18px 0;
  
  order: -3; /* place the divs before the buttons */
}

#content-0 {
  display: block;
  background: cyan;
}

#content-1 {
  background: hotpink;
}

#content-2 {
  background: red;
}

#content-3 {
  background: blue;
}

#btn-1:hover ~ #content-1,
#btn-2:hover ~ #content-2,
#btn-3:hover ~ #content-3 {
  display: block;
}

#btn-1:hover ~ #content-0,
#btn-2:hover ~ #content-0,
#btn-3:hover ~ #content-0 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="btn-1">Button 1</button>
  <button id="btn-2">Button 2</button>
  <button id="btn-3">Button 3</button>

  <div id="content-0">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem 
  </div>
  <div id="content-1">
    A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like 
  </div>
  <div id="content-2">
    One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he  
  </div>
  <div id="content-3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. A
  </div>
</div>
```

(Clearly, the divs can be filled and styled as you like)

Comment: I have the basic functionality working now, however, the buttons in question are not in the same div as the header content. They occupy separate containers, and I can't get it to work. (It works if I create a few buttons inside of the header container, though.). The other thing I've noticed is that the CSS transition property doesn't work. The content changes abruptly regardless of what I've done to try and ease them together. Any advice?